# Error in ASP classic upload form ( ASP Uploader)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working on a ASP classic website In that I'd a requirement of  uploading images to website. My website is hosted on 1 & 1. I've downloaded ASP up-loader and wrote the following code suggested in ASP Up-loader help page http://aspuploader.com/Deployment.html. My code looks like

```
Dim uploader2   
Set uploader2=new AspUploader         
uploader2.Name="myuploader"   
uploader2.SaveDirectory="savefiles" 
uploader2.AllowedFileExtensions="*.jpg,*.png,*.gif"          
uploader2.Render()
```

and my html page looks something  like this

```
<div>
<table>
<tr>       
<td>  Upload Image:
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this); "  name="File1"  />
<img id="img" src="#" alt="your image" />
</td>          
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Now My question is after running the above code I ran into following error

> Scripting.FileSystemObject error '80040401'
>
> Permission Denied
> /aspuploader/resources/coreimpl.js, line 1

I have changed file permissions also in 1 & 1 for my webfiles but still I'm getting same error message.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in http://aspuploader.com/Deployment.html to setup the example? If so `savefiles` should be located in `http://{your site}/{your application}/aspuploader/` that means you should have a Classic ASP web application defined in IIS with a sub folder `aspuploader` for the example to work correctly. You will also need to make sure that IIS anonymous account has at least read access to all files in that folder and probably read/write in the `/aspuploader/savefiles` folder.